# How to work with a DataFrame which cannot be transformed by pandas pivot due to excessive memory usage?

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataframe with this structure

[image]

i built this dfp with 100 rows of the original for testing

[image]

and then i tried to make a pivot operation to get a dataframe like this

[image]

The problem with the pivot operations using all data is that the solution would have 131209 rows and 39123 columns. When I try the operation the memory collapse and restar my pc.

I tried segmenting the dataframe with 10 or 20. The pivot works but when I do a concat operation it crashes the memory again.

[image]

My pc have 16gb of memory. I have also tried with collabs but it also collapses the memory.

Is there a format or another strategy to work on this operation?

Comment: If your `my_columns` values are small enough to fit in a data type which is smaller than the current data type then try that. That should significantly reduce the memory. For example reducing from float64 to float16

Comment: My column is a column with value 1 in all columns

Answer (score 1):

You may try this,

```
dfu = dfp.groupby(['order_id','product_id'])[['my_column']].sum().unstack().fillna(0)
```

Another way is you split `product_id` to process and concatinate back to ,

```
front_part = []
rear_part = []
dfp_f = dfp[dfp['product_id'].isin(front_part)]
dfp_r = dfp[dfp['product_id'].isin(rear_part)]

dfs_f = dfp_f.pivot(index='order_id', columns='product_id', values=['my_column']).fillna(0)
dfs_r = dfp_r.pivot(index='order_id', columns='product_id', values=['my_column']).fillna(0)
dfs = pd.concat([dfs_f, dfs_r], axis=1)
```

`front_part`, `rear_part` means we wanna separate `product_id` into two parts, but we need to specify the discrete numerical value into lists.